# Tangent bundle of the complex manifold

Tags: manifolds, complex-geometry

Let U be an open subset of the coordinate space $C^n$, the book then says the total space of the tangent bundle $r_U$ is $DU=U \times C^n$ and it has a canonical complex structure $J_0$ defined by $$J_0(u,v)=(u,iv)$$
But if we view U as a 2n-dimensional real space, the tangent space on each point p is a 2n-dimensional real vector space $T_pU$, but its complexification is $T_pU\otimes C \subset C^{2n}$, not a n-dimensional complex vector space. So if we call the tangent space of a subset in $C^n$, do we mean that we view it as a complex manifold and view the tangent space as the holomorphic tangent subspace of the space $T_pU \otimes C$? If it is the case, does it mean that we just consider the holomorphic functions on U? What's the explicit expression of this tangent space?I'm a new learner and a little bit confused.

Comment: It might be useful to say which book you are following, and give the relevant pages.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you identify the complex tangent space $\mathbf{C}^{n}$ with the real space $\mathbf{R}^{2n}$, then there's no need to complexify $T_{p}U$ to get the tangent space to $U$ at $p$...?